# PHP contact form not displaying server results on same page when submitted

Tags: php, ajax, captcha, contact-form

i have a contact form with a CAPTCHA, everything's works great to the point where the form is submitted.

It sends the e-mail with the information filled in the form.

But, when submitted the server results display in a blank page unformatted. But the server results should been displayed on the same page inside a specific div.

It worked before but I updated the captcha and it doesn't work anymore. And a can't find the problem. I'm far for being fluent in PHP.

Thank you by advance.

Frédéric

The PHP page with the contact form :

```
<?php
    // Start a session.
    session_start();

    // Include the IconCaptcha classes.
    require('IconCaptcha-PHP/src/captcha-session.class.php');
    require('IconCaptcha-PHP/src/captcha.class.php');

    use IconCaptcha\IconCaptcha;

    // Set the IconCaptcha options.
    IconCaptcha::options([
        'iconPath' => dirname(__FILE__) . '/IconCaptcha-PHP/assets/icons', // required, change path according to your installation.
        //'themes' => [
        //    'black' => [
        //        'icons' => 'light', // Which icon type should be used: light or dark.
        //        'color' => [20, 20, 20], // Array contains the icon separator border color, as RGB.
        //    ]
        //],
        'messages' => [
            'wrong_icon' => 'Mauvaise image',
            'no_selection' => 'Aucune image séléctionnée',
            'empty_form' => 'Formulaire vide',
            'invalid_id' => 'The captcha ID was invalid.',
            'form_token' => 'The form token was invalid.'
        ],
        'image' => [
            'amount' => [ // min & max can be 5 - 8
                'min' => 5,
                'max' => 8
            ],
            'rotate' => false,
            'flip' => [
                'horizontally' => false,
                'vertically' => false,
            ],
            'border' => true
        ],
        'attempts' => [
            'amount' => 5,
            'timeout' => 60 // seconds.
        ],
        'token' => true
    ]);
    
    // If the form has been submitted, validate the captcha.
    if(!empty($_POST)) {
        if(IconCaptcha::validateSubmission($_POST)) {
            // Captcha submission was valid.
        } else {
            // Captcha submission was not valid.
        }
    }
?>

<!doctype html>


<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]>      <html class="no-js"> <![endif]-->

        <!--FORMAT-->
        <html lang="fr" xml:lang="fr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">

    
        <!-- Bootstrap 4.3.1 CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    
        <!-- Feuilles de style -->
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
            
        <!-- Normalize -->
        <link href="css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
            
        <!-- IconCaptcha -->
        <link href="IconCaptcha-PHP/assets/css/icon-captcha.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="IconCaptcha-PHP/assets/js/icon-captcha.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            
    </head> 
                        
    <body>
        
        
        <section id="contact" class="contacter">
            <div class="subcontent">
                            <div class="sous-titres-txt" style="text-align: center;">
                <br><br><h1>Modèle de formulaire de contact</h1><br><br>
            </div>
            <div class="" style="width: 90%; text-align: center; margin:0px auto;">
             <div class="form-group center-block" style="text-align: center; align-content: center">   
<!-- DEBUT FORMULAIRE CONTACT -->
                     <?php
                    if(isset($captchaMessage)) {
                        echo '<b>Captcha Message: </b>' . $captchaMessage;
                    }
                ?>
                    <form id="reused_form" role="form" method="post" action="envoiformulaire.php" style="font-family: 'Montserrat-ExtraLight'">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                        <label for="first_name"></label>
                                        <input id="firstname" name="first_name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Prénom">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                        <label for="last_name"></label>
                                        <input id="lastname" name="last_name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="NOM">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                        <label for="email"></label>
                                        <input id="email" name="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Courriel">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                        <label for="telephone"></label>
                                        <input id="telephone" type="tel" name="telephone" onkeyup="formatte(this,2)" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" class="form-control" placeholder="Téléphone" minlength="14" maxlength="14">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                                        <label for="comments"></label>
                                        <textarea id="message" name="comments" class="form-control" placeholder="Message (400 caractères maximum)" rows="4" required="required"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12 form-group" style="padding-top: 20px">
                                      <!-- Additional security token to prevent CSRF. Optional but highly recommended - disable via IconCaptcha options. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="_iconcaptcha-token" value="<?= IconCaptcha::token() ?>"/>

    <!-- The IconCaptcha will be rendered in this element -->
    <div class="iconcaptcha-holder" data-theme="light"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                                   <br> <input type="submit" id="btnContactUs" class="btn" value="Envoyer le message">
                                </div>
                            </div> <br>
 <div id="server-results" style="border-radius: 5px; background-color: #005C7B; color: #fff; font-family: 'Montserrat-ExtraLight'";><!-- FEEDBACKS du formulaire --></div>
                    </form>
                    
        <!-- Initialize IconCaptcha -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    
    // Plain JavaScript implementation.
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        IconCaptcha.init('.iconcaptcha-holder', {
            general: {
                validationPath: 'IconCaptcha-PHP/src/captcha-request.php', // required, change path according to your installation.
                fontFamily: 'Montserrat-ExtraLight',
                credits: 'show',
            },
            security: {
                clickDelay: 500,
                hoverDetection: true,
                enableInitialMessage: true,
                initializeDelay: 500,
                selectionResetDelay: 3000,
                loadingAnimationDelay: 1000,
                invalidateTime: 1000 * 60 * 2, // 2 minutes, in milliseconds
            },
            messages: {
                initialization: {
                    verify: 'Vérification anti-spam (cliquer).',
                    loading: 'Chargement du jeu...'
                },
                header: "Sélectionner l'image <b>la moins souvent</b> affichée",
                correct: 'Anti-spam validé',
                incorrect: {
                    title: 'Oh non, quelle horreur.',
                    subtitle: "Vous avez choisi la mauvaise image."
                },
                timeout: {
                    title: "Merci d'attendre 60 secondes.",
                    subtitle: "Trop d'échecs successifs."
                }
            }
        });
    });

</script>
        <script>
        $("#reused_form").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); //prevent default action 
    var post_url = $(this).attr("action"); //get form action url
    var request_method = $(this).attr("method"); //get form GET/POST method
    var form_data = $(this).serialize(); //Encode form elements for submission
    
    $.ajax({
        url : post_url,
        type: request_method,
        data : form_data
    }).done(function(response){ //
        $("#server-results").html(response);
    });
});// JavaScript Document
        </script>
<!-- FIN FORMULAIRE CONTACT -->
          </div>
            </div>                      

             </div>
        </section>
        
                

        <!-- SCRIPTS -->
        
        <!-- jQuery 3.3.1 -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
            
        <!-- Bootstrap 4.3.1 JS -->
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        
        <!-- DIVERS -->
        <script src="js/format_tel.js"></script>
        <script src="js/isNumberKey.js"></script>
        

    </body>
</html>
```

The PHP process to check and validate the form, and to send the e-mail :

```
<?php

session_start();

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

require('IconCaptcha-PHP/src/captcha-session.class.php');
require('IconCaptcha-PHP/src/captcha.class.php');

use IconCaptcha\IconCaptcha;

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    function died($error) {
        echo " <br>Oh, quelle horreur ! <br>";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // Validate the captcha.
    if(!IconCaptcha::validateSubmission($_POST)) {
        died('CAPTCHA non validé!');
        // died('CAPTCHA non validé! - ' . IconCaptcha::getErrorMessage());
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('Oups ! Un problème est survenu avec votre formulaire. Veuillez recommencer');
    }

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // requis
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // requis
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // requis
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // requis
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

    $error_message = "";

    $email_exp ='/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/'; // vérifier absence de caractères interdits

    if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
        $error_message .= 'Le courriel saisi ne semble pas valide.<br />';
    }
    $phone_exp = "/^\d{2}\s\d{2}\s\d{2}\s\d{2}\s\d{2}/"; // de la forme XX XX XX XX XX avec 14 caractères

    if(!preg_match( $phone_exp,$telephone)) {
        $error_message .= 'Le numéro de téléphone saisi ne semble pas valide.<br />';
    }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z àèìòùÀÈÌÒÙáéíóúýÁÉÍÓÚÝâêîôûÂÊÎÔÛãñõÃÑÕäëïöüÿÄËÏÖÜŸçÇßØøÅåÆæœ.'-]+$/"; // lettres uniquement avec accents

    if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
        $error_message .= 'Le prénom saisi ne semble pas valide.<br />';
    }

    if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
        $error_message .= 'Le nom saisi ne semble pas valide.<br />';
    }

    if(strlen($comments) < 2) { // message en dessous de 2 caractères
        $error_message .= 'Le message saisi ne semble pas valide.<br />';
    }

    if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
        died($error_message);
    }

    if(strlen($error_message) < 1)  {
        echo " <br>Le message a bien été envoyé, merci ! <br> <br> ";
    }

    $email_message = "Ci-après le formulaire complété.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
        $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
        return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "Prénom: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "NOM: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Courriel: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Téléphone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

    $email_to = « coucou@coucou.com;
    $email_subject = "Nouveau message web";

    // create email headers
    $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
        'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
        'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"'.
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
}
```

Comment: It's quite confusing code to read through as there is a lot there that plays no part in your problem I suspect but the PHP script that processes the form data and sends the mail does not output anything (unless there is an error by the looks of it) so the ajax callback has nothing to work with

Comment: Thank you for your message, I copied all the lines used for the from, to avoid missing something. The form works and there is an output when submitted I have the success message but on a blank page. The lines in the process are :  if(strlen($error_message) < 1)  {
        echo " <br>Le message a bien été envoyé, merci ! <br> <br> "; »

Comment: I find it very confusing.  You have some of the code repeated. - IconCaptcha::validateSubmission   Which one actually runs?  If the email is sent then the second one runs.  Is it in a different file?

Comment: Yes the Captcha is on another file. It validates in the main page and the form process check if it's been validated. You can see it here https://www.agence-mibe.com/CONTACTFORM/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tried to change the Ajax response with the following code, but i still have the server results in a blank page, not on the same within the specific div

```html
    <script>
      $("#reused_form").submit(function(event) {
          event.preventDefault(); //prevent default action 
          let post_url = $(this).attr("action"); //get form action url
          let form_data = $(this).serialize(); //Encode form elements for submission        
          $.post(post_url, form_data, function(response) {
            $("#server-results").html(response);
          });
        });
    </script>
```

I still don't know where the problem is

Comment: This should be appended to your question.  This is not an answer !

Comment: I tried this method to : 
 <script>
      $("#my_form").submit(function(event) {
          event.preventDefault(); //prevent default action 
          let post_url = $(this).attr("action"); //get form action url
          let form_data = $(this).serialize(); //Encode form elements for submission       
          $.get(post_url, form_data, function(response) {
            $("#server-results").html(response);
          });
        });
    </script>
 But the server response still get in a blank page

Comment: So I found the problem. jQuery wasn't working with a link on it's main server, I tried to download it and hosted it on my server.